# Finding all topological orders

Tags: graph, topological-sort

I have to make an algorithm that finds all the topological orders(using predecessor counting) and the highest cost paths and their costs between 2 pairs of vertices. My algorithm looks like this for now:

```
 def topologicalSort(self):
        sorted = []
        count = {}
        q = deque()
        for x in self.parseX():
            count[x] = self.innerDegree(x)
            if count[x] == 0:
                q.append(x)
        while len(q) > 0:
            x = q.popleft()
            sorted.append(x)
            for y in self.parseNout(x):
                count[y] -= 1
                if count[y] == 0:
                    q.append(y)
        return sorted
```

It works fine but the problem is that is will find only one topological order. And my question would be: How can I make it to find all the topological orders?

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are in a fixed order. Different topological sorts are achieved by iterating over them in different orders. So you need another level of recursion trying an topological sort on each of them being the first one to be tried.

I'd elaborate, but cursory search found several pages apparently describing the algorithm you want (albeit in different languages):

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/all-topological-sorts-of-a-directed-acyclic-graph/
- https://www.techiedelight.com/find-all-possible-topological-orderings-of-dag/